# Why does the JavaScript Dropdown button not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I used the addEventListener to my html dropdown form in JavaScript but it is not working. I'm supposed to use the dropdown to select between 3 colors --Blue, Violet, and Pink-- to change the color of the header. The expected result is the header color changing based off what I select in the dropdown option. For instance if I select Blue it should change the header color to blue. The same goes for the other color options.

The actual result is the header color remaining constant no matter which color I select, how many times I click or how many times I refresh to start over. There are no error messages so I do not know what is wrong.

I have looked over my code several times and asked the person who taught this lesson but I cannot find where the problem is and I have not received a response in almost a week. I even asked the instructor for help again with a picture of the code but I still haven't received a response.

My code is pretty long and it would require me to take multiple screen shots. I don't think that would be efficient in helping you understand the code and I don't think pasting the whole thing would help either. Despite that I will add more information if you need it and include a paste of the code

```
        dropdown.addEventListener("input", function() {
        /* Add class to header based off what is put down as header */
        console.log(dropdown.value);
        header.classList = ""; /* Take the class list and refresh it. Makes it so when you have a violet class and blue class it doesn't add both (only have one class at a time) */
        header.classList.add(dropdown.value); /* Changes the color of the h1 */
    });
```

[dropdown javascript code that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY4Jc.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a complete example.

Comment: It has all the requirements from the forum.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't. Your own answer refers to HTML and CSS that we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a dropdown (select element) changing the class of a header element. Use `className` to clear the list. `classList` is a set of methods, not a string. Use `change` for the event since dropdowns (selects or otherwise) don't have an `input` event.

```js
let dropdown, header
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
  header = document.querySelector('header');
  dropdown.addEventListener("change", e => {
    header.className = ''
    header.classList.add(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #000;
  padding:15px;
}

.violet {
  background: violet;
  color: #fff;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>The header</h2>
</header>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option value='violet'>violet</option>
  <option value='red'>red</option>
  <option value='green'>green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I didn't use everything else but I was able to make it work by adding classes of the colors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown.addEventListener("input")` should be `dropdown.addEventListener("change")` which will run the function whenever the dropdown value changes.

Comment: Hello Culiynl, thank you for your quick resposnse. Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out all I had to do was add classes of the colors in the style section of the html. Thanks to everybody who responded and helped me. This is what worked for me.
      `.blue { color: blue; } .violet { color: darkviolet; } .pink {color: deeppink;}`